# GPO error opening

Tags: group-policy

I encountered an issue while attempting to create a duplicate of an existing mapped drive Group Policy Object (GPO) and modifying it for a different path in my environment. Unfortunately, I made a mistake by specifying an incorrect path, resulting in an error. Although I promptly removed the GPO, I'm still encountering the same error when trying to navigate to the user configuration and preferences section.
[image]
This problem seems to affect all my GPOs, and even restoring a backup from another domain controller did not resolve the issue.

Comment: `restoring a backup from another domain controller did not resolve the issue.` You need to restore from a backup created before the files were destroyed.